# Axis url template interceptor throws error

Tags: axios, react-typescript

As per the documentation [axios-url-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-url-template) I'm trying to use the url template interceptor for my `react` `typescript` app,

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(urlTemplateInterceptor({
  urlAsTemplate: true,
}));
```

However it throws following error. What am I missing?

```js
    Argument of type '(config: AxiosRequestConfig<any>) => AxiosRequestConfig<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>) => InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any> | Promise<InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>>'.
      Type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>' is not assignable to type 'InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any> | Promise<InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>>'.
        Type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>' is not assignable to type 'InternalAxiosRequestConfig<any>'.
          Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
            Type 'AxiosHeaders | (Partial<RawAxiosHeaders & { Accept: AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Length": AxiosHeaderValue; "User-Agent": AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Encoding": AxiosHeaderValue; Authorization: AxiosHeaderValue; } & { ...; }> & Partial<...>) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<RawAxiosHeaders & { Accept: AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Length": AxiosHeaderValue; "User-Agent": AxiosHeaderValue; "Content-Encoding": AxiosHeaderValue; Authorization: AxiosHeaderValue; } & { ...; }>'.ts(2345)
    (alias) urlTemplateInterceptor(options?: UrlTemplateInterceptorOptions | undefined): (config: AxiosRequestConfig<any>) => AxiosRequestConfig<any>
    import urlTemplateInterceptor
```

Comment: It seems that the Axios version you are using expects a different function signature for interceptors.

Comment: thanks @YigitYasar, spot on. It's a version issue. Looks like `axios-url-template` does not support latest versions of `axios`.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented custom interceptor as needed and that worked.

```js
// just remove the templates as we wont be using /{id} pattern
axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (!config.url) {
    return config;
  }

  if (config.url.indexOf("{") === -1) {
    return {
      ...config,
      url: config.url,
    };
  } else {
    return {
      ...config,
      url: config.url.split("{")[0],
    };
  }
});
```